# Col A is a subspace in $R^ p$ and Nul A is a subspace in $R^ q$ . Find the values of p and q.

Tags: matrices

```
 −3.1 21  12  5  17

 -2   27 −13  3  −1

  4   1   0   6  3
```

My first thoughts are that P is 5, given the number of columns and Q is 3 given the number of rows. However, that seems too simple. Can someone offer some insight. Thanks.

Comment: The correct answer is equally simple (so it isn't too simple), but yours is *not* correct.  Hint: name any vector in Col $A$?

Comment: I mean, (1,1,1,1,1) can be the X vector for a set of column A, but how does that relate?

Comment: Do you know what Col $A$ means?  How do you know that $(1,1,1,1,1)$ is in the column space of $A$?

Comment: As I understand it Col A is the subspace spanned by the columns of A, (1,1,1,1,1) isn't IN the subspace, it is an example of the x vectors that you could use to create the vectors that are, in this case, it is just the matrix itself.

Comment: Good, you've identified that $(1,1,1,1,1)$ is *not* in the column space of $A$.  Now pick any vector that is... any vector at all.

Comment: So, (5, 3, 6) would work right?

Comment: Yes.  Which $\mathbb R^p$ does $(5,3,6)$ belong to?  Which $\mathbb R^p$ does everything in Col $A$ belong to?  $\mathbb R^3$ of course.  Once you actually read what the question is asking, it's very simple.

Comment: Right, and the same thing for Nul Space (?). Ok, that is even simpler than I thought. Thanks.